# How to merge results on 2 indices in ElasticSearch?

Tags: php, elasticsearch, lucene, yii2

I have **2 indices** `documents_1` and `documents_2` in ElasticSearch with different mapping types (they have some different attributes). I am using `Yii2` framework on `php` to search on web.

**Question:** How can I search over 2 indices (if it is possible) and merge results in one sorted by date for example? To explain I do need something like this:

```
$queryOne = DocumentOne::find()->all();
$queryTwo = DocumentTwo::find()->all();

merge_results($queryOne, $queryTwo);
```

DocumentOne.php

```
class DocumentOne extends \yii\elasticsearch\ActiveRecord
{
    public static function index()
    {
        return 'documents_1';
    }

    public static function type()
    {
        return 'type_a';
    }

    public function attributes()
    {
        return ['id', 'any_1', 'created_format_1'];
    }
}
```

DocumentTwo.php

```
class DocumentTwo extends \yii\elasticsearch\ActiveRecord
{
    public static function index()
    {
        return 'documents_2';
    }

    public static function type()
    {
        return 'type_b';
    }

    public function attributes()
    {
        return ['id', 'any_2', 'created_format_2'];
    }
}
```

DocumentOneSearch.php

```
class DocumentOneSearch extends DocumentOne
{
    public function search($params)
    {
        $query = DocumentOne::find();
        $sort = new Sort([
            'defaultOrder' => [
                'created_format_1' => SORT_DESC,
            ],
        ]);

        return $query
            ->orderBy($sort->orders)
            ->all();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered something like:

```
function cmp($a, $b)
{
    return strcmp($a->date, $b->date);
}

$queryOne = DocumentOne::find()->all();
$queryTwo = DocumentTwo::find()->all();

$result = array_merge($queryOne, $queryTwo);

usort($result, "cmp");
```

assuming that your documents have a property named `date`?

**edit:** If you only needs the first set of results to be sorted, then you could just [array_merge()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php) the results

Comment: thank you for your answer. what if there are more than 10 millions results? will it work good?

Comment: You should definitely consider pagination when dealing with so many results